# Null value than rename file

Tags: sed, perl, rename, cut, null

I have a shell to a task but I should handle the null value in this.
So in the task i cut the part of a word and i delete or rename the file, but need another if element for null.

For example:
I have word "pear" and I cut it all with this and the filename null:

```
echo $fname | perl -p -e 's/:pear://g'
```

I should rename now to "nullfile".

Comment: Would you so kind to show two examples (with null value and w/o). E.g. `pearlast —> nulllast` ; `last —> nullfile`

Comment: I have file "pear" and i cut "pear" than it is a null filename. I should rename this to NULLFILE

pear -> nothing
pear-> nullfile

Comment: Why you need **cut** *pear* if you just need to **exchange** it to *nullfile*? `echo "${fname/pear/nullfile}"`

Comment: for fname in $(find . -type f)                    
do                              
     van=$(echo $(basename $fname) | grep ':pear:' | wc -l)    
     if [ $van -eq 1  ]  ; then              
          newname=$(echo $fname | perl -p -e 's/:pear://g')    
          if [ -e $newname ] ; then            
               rm -f $newname               
               echo "Deleted file $newname"     
          fi
          mv $fname $newname               
          echo "Renamed file $fname to $newname" 
     fi
done

Comment: This is my full example. And i must write an IF what happens if i cut all the file name.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us examples of the possible values of `$fname`. We need to see two examples, one that is "null" and one that is not. It is very hard to understand your question at the moment. You also need to explain i) are all the files in the same directory? ii) do we need to search subdirectories? iii) will the name contain `pear` or `:pear:`? iv) what happens if there are more than one "nullfiles"?

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
newname=${${fname//:pear:}:-nullfile}
```

With `bash` or `ksh93`, you have to do it in two steps:

```
newname=${fname//:pear:}
newname=${newname:-nullfile}
```

POSIXly, to remove all occurrences of a string, you need to do it as:

```
newname=$(
  printf '%s\n' "$fname" | sed 's/:pear://g'; echo .
)
newname=${newname%??}
newname=${newname:-nullfile}
```

You can simplify it to:

```
newname=$(
  printf '%s\n' "$fname" | sed 's/:pear://g'
)
newname=${newname:-nullfile}
```

If you can guarantee that `$fname` won't end in newline characters.

Comment: Why do you need to `echo .`? In a POSIX shell is it a problem for a command substitution to return an empty string?

Comment: @glennjackman, no the problem is that command substitution trims all trailing newline characters, so if you have a filename that ends in a newline character, that will remove it. _If you can guarantee `$fname` won't end in newline characters_, see the simpler version underneath.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
{ read -r dirname fname
  read second
} < <(find . -type f -name '*:pear:*' -printf '%h %f\n')
if [ -z "$second" -a -n "$fname" ] ; then
    newname="${fname/:pear:/}"
    if [ -e "$dirname/${newname:=nullfile}" ] ; then
        rm -f "$dirname/$newname"
        echo "Deleted file $dirname/$newname"
    fi 
    mv "$dirname/"{"$fname", "$newname"}
    echo "Renamed file $dirname/$fname to $dirname/$newname"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameter substitution to provide a default value if the variable is empty:

```
$ filename="string of pearls"
$ newname=$( sed 's/pear//g' <<<"$filename" )
$ echo "${newname:-nullfile}"
string of ls
```

```
$ filename=pear
$ newname=$( sed 's/pear//g' <<<"$filename" )
$ echo "${newname:-nullfile}"
nullfile
```

In fact you don't even need to call out to sed or perl: parameter substitution 4 teh win!

```
$ filename="spear pearl"
$ newname=${filename//pear/}
$ echo "${newname:-nullfile}"
s l
```

```
$ filename=pear
$ newname=${filename//pear/}
$ echo "${newname:-nullfile}"
nullfile
```